# Updating app without any change in .apk file

Tags: android, auto-update, apk

I am not sure that it's a real question or not . But It would be great if anybody can help me on this .

I want to know that is it possible in android to keep the resources in a folder in FTP server and let the application check that if there are some updated files in the folder and send a notification to user if any updates are available without any change in .apk file ?

Comment: Well, technically, yes, just store it in a remote server as XML file, and then fetch it and save it somewhere on the disk, then inflate it to use it. But that doesn't sound like a very good way to do this, why don't you want to update the APK file?

Comment: My client wants to change the resources (like images and html files) by their own and want to send a notification to user without any help of the developer.. or without changing the apk file from the google play..

Comment: @ Nibha: You can download images and stored in application memory without intervention of developer but the bottleneck will be the i/o time required to read from memory and creating bitmap at runtime. And for HTML you can use webView to access the updated pages by hitting client server which has updated pages.

Comment: Building on what @Rollno1 stated, use a `WebView` that links to whatever page your client needs, then your client can just update that page with regular HTML/JavaScript/PHP... and whenever the user launches the app, it just loads that page. Let me know.

Comment: And consider saving a cached version of the page, in case the user does not have Internet access at times.

Comment: @NibhaJain: Vote up if resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you're getting with this, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

You can just update your app in Google Play, and this will be pretty much taken care for you. Users can also choose to get updates for applications automatically.

However, Yes, An android app can for example initiate requests to web services (Or ftp servers) and fetch data.

Comment: Consider productive replies. This doesn't help in any way, nor it is an answer. First ask the why, then when the info is clear, provide your knowledge, cheers :)